# NLP: Automatically categorize words semantically into non-predefined classes

Tags: natural-language-processing

I am looking for a method to categorize a given word into semantically into classes. A simple example would be:

`chair -> furniture`

The most reasonable way to do so that comes to my mind, would be to create a tree containing words, where `chair` is a predecessor of `furniture`. Then one could define a threshold that describes the level of the tree predecessor that should be taken as the result.

Is there some existing research/tools or even trees that fulfill the described task? I cannot find anything in google because I do not know the specific term for my problem. *Keyword Clustering* as a technique seems a little different, because is works on existing data and return multiple matches.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for Wordnet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet ...

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.